# 40-60s short story: nuclear explosions slow time

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, nuclear-weapons

Read this short story in a collection of classic scifi stories I'll guess published 1940s - 1960s.

During an atomic war, 3 simultaneous nuclear explosions happen over a small American town. The exact second of the explosions fracture time.

The residents can see the fireballs creeping slowly toward their town but life goes on, daily chores, mowing the lawn etc.

One family tries to escape and drive through the event horizon of the light blast, but 100 feet or so inside of that bubble is the approaching heat wave.

Comment: Sounds a little like the 19**80** film The Day Time Ended, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_Time_Ended

Comment: That storyline has similarities, perhaps the screen writer was influenced by the same short story I'd read.